# how to change ADDED interface names and make them persistent

Tags: 16.04, networking, interface

After looking around a bit on the internet I discovered that the **'** Predictable **'** Network Interface Names is making the network interface names 'Predictable'.


Well you can already guess what is going on. I now have interface names that are ridiculously long but I was able to fix the builtin interfaces back to the good old eth0 and eth1, but now the new added ones get an even larger string of characters which is quite annoying, as I need to type the whole thing out. after looking around for solutions on the internet to get them to be named like the other two I only found temporarily solutions and I need a persistent solution as the server needs to be rebooted sometimes for certain upgrades/updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a persistent name to predictable interfaces as explained here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html

You should only need to match the MAC e.g

```
/etc/systemd/network/10-dmz.link

[Match]
MACAddress=00:a0:de:63:7a:e6

[Link]
Name=dmz0
```

So you can have predictable names enabled but have it the old way to some degree.

---

It'll be nice when predicatable names all TAB complete because they are a pain imo.